# Внешние события C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, события

Программа должна выводить в консоль код нажаой клавишы, но проблема в том, что программа дважды реагирует на одно нажатие. В дебаггере отловить ошибку не получилось - т.к. в дебаггере программа отрабатывает корректно.
Не могу разобраться в чем проблема.
Буду благодарен за помощь.

```
#include "Windows.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

HHOOK hookHandle;
HINSTANCE appInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
LRESULT CALLBACK keyHandler(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
int codeKeyBigR = 82;
int codeKeySmallR = 114;

int codeKeySlash = 0xDC;

int main(int argc, TCHAR* argv[]) {

    hookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, keyHandler, appInstance, 0);

    if (hookHandle == NULL) {
        cout << "ERROR CREATING HOOK: ";
        cout << GetLastError() << endl;
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }

    MSG message;

    while (GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0) != 0) {
        TranslateMessage(&message);
        DispatchMessage(&message);
    }

    cout << "Press any key to quit...";
    getchar();

    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hookHandle);

    return 0;
}


LRESULT CALLBACK keyHandler(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

    int key = ((KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam)->vkCode;

    // Checks whether params contain action about keystroke
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION) {
        cout << "Keycode \"" << key << "\" was pressed" << endl;

        else if (key == codeKeySlash)
        {
            exit(0);
        }

    }

    return CallNextHookEx(hookHandle, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Она у вас, как я понимаю, отрабатывает и нажатие, *и отпускание* клавиши...

Comment: да, скорее всего так и есть. Поэтому и в дебаггере не получилось отловить. Отжатие происходило когда программа останавливалась в точке останова.
Не подскажете, как сделать, что бы программа срабатывала только при нажатии?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исправьте строчку вывода на

```
cout << "Keycode \"" << key << "\" was " <<
    ((((KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam)->flags&LLKHF_UP) ? "released" : " pressed") << endl;
```

и вы увидите, что программа честно отрабатывает нажатие и отпускание клавиши.

Ну, если вы еще исправите несбалансированный if-else, понятно :)

Comment: Спасибо, я пол дня голову ломал)

Comment: Ну, если вопрос решен - можете пометить ответ как принятый (птичка слева от него).